# Hosting Behind Airport Extreme

Tags: web-hosting, mac

I'm trying to set up a simple web service (running on a macbook) over a custom port behind a Airport Extreme connected to a D-link cable modem that runs on Time Warner.

Reading from https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3415, I set up port forwarding on the Airport extreme.  But it doesn't seem to work when I'm curling the IP with the port.  I also have apache running and set up a virtual host with proxypass from / to http://localhost:9292

For example:

- Airport Extreme has IP addr 72.68.0.10
- Internet router has IP addr 72.68.0.11
- Macbook has internal IP addr 10.0.1.10
- Service running on port 8000

Connection gets dropped when I curl 10.0.1.10:8000 or 72.68.0.11:8000.  Does anyone know how to get a setup like this working?

Answer (score 1):

The cable modem isn't performing the port forwarding, the Airport is. You need to port forward 72.68.0.10:8000 to 10.0.1.10:8000.